# Does super() run in compiletime and this() run in runtime? and why?

Tags: java, oop, this, superclass

in this program it will print "Student 1 Person 1 Undergrad 2 "

that means super.method1() > super() of student
this.method2() this of Undergrad()

Does super() run in compiletime and  this() run in runtime? and why  ?

```
public class Person {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print("Person 1 ");
    }
    public void method2()  {
        System.out.print("Person 2 ");
    }
}
```

```
public class Student extends Person {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print("Student 1 ");
        super.method1();
        this.method2();
    }
    public void method2() {
        System.out.print("Student 2 ");
    }
}
```

```
public class Undergrad extends Student {
     /*public void method1() {
         System.out.print("ahmed");
     }*/
     public void method2() {
         System.out.print("Undergrad 2 ");
     }
}
```

```
public class main {
    
    static void main(){
        Person u = new Undergrad();
        u.method1();    
        
    }

}
```

I expect output: It will cause an infinite execution, printing "Student 1" over and over.

output was:"Student 1 Person 1 Undergrad 2 ".

Comment: /*what output you expect of that*/  public class Student extends Person {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print("Student 1 ");
        super.method2();
        this.method2();
    }
    public void method2() {
        System.out.print("Student 2 ");
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that `super.xxx()` vs `this.xxx()` has some sort of a "compile time vs runtime" distinction, but it is certainly not that `super.xxx()` is "*run*" at compile time.

A more accurate wording would be, the method that will be called by a `super.xxx` call is decided at compile time (*statically dispatched*). And the method that will be called by a `this.xxx` call is decided at runtime (*dynamically dispatched*).

You can see this by comparing the clauses in the Java Language Specification, in the sections about processing method invocations. The important steps that differs between `super.xxx` and `this.xxx` are (emphasis mine):

#### [Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Type to Search](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)

> If the form is `Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then let T be the type of the Primary expression. The type to search is T if T is a class or interface type, or the upper bound of T if T is a type variable.
>
> If the form is `super . [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then the type to search is the direct superclass type of **the class whose declaration contains the method invocation**.

Notice that this is done at compile time. The call `super.method1();` in `Student` will cause a search in `Person` because `Person` is "the class whose declaration contains the method invocation". Eventually, we'll find `Person.method1` in a later step.

On the other hand, the call `this.method2();` in `Student` will search in `Student`.

#### [Locate Method to Invoke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.4)

> - Let `Q` be the qualifying class or interface of the method invocation (§13.1).
> - Let `m` be the method found in Q or a superclass or superinterface of Q. (Note that m was merely the name of the method in the previous
>   section; here it is the actual declaration.)
> - Let `C` be the class or interface that declares m.
>
> [...]
>
> - **If the invocation mode is `super`, overriding is not allowed. Method m of class or interface C is the one to be invoked.** If m is abstract,
>   an AbstractMethodError is thrown.
>
> [...]
>
> - Otherwise, the invocation mode is `interface` or `virtual`.
>
>   If the method m of class or interface C is private, then it is the method to be invoked.
>
>   Otherwise, overriding may occur. **A dynamic method lookup, specified below, is used to locate the method to invoke.** The lookup
>   procedure starts from class R, the actual run-time class of the target
>   object.

This is a runtime step. For `super.method1();`, `C` is `Person` (since we found `Person.method1()`), and the invocation mode is `super`, so that is what is invoked.

For `this.method2();`, a dynamic method lookup occurs, which in this case involves finding the appropriate overridden method depending on the runtime type of `this`.